# Как скрыть секцию в tableView если в секции ячейки пустые SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4, tableview

У меня есть 3 секции в которые добавляются продукты по их типу

```
   var productsList = BasketModel.shared.records
    var sections: [String] = ["Блюда","Топинги","Напитки"]
    var sectionedProducts: [[Products]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        choiceBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        choiceBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        basketTableView.delegate = self
        basketTableView.dataSource = self
        orderButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        orderButton.layer.masksToBounds = true



        if !BasketModel.shared.records.isEmpty {
            fullBasketview.isHidden = false
            sections.forEach { section in

                let itemsInSection = productsList.filter({$0.type == section})
                sectionedProducts.append(itemsInSection)
                for item in itemsInSection {
                    totalPrice += item.price
                    totalPriceLabel.text = "\(totalPrice) Руб."
                }
            }

        } else {
            sectionedProducts.removeAll()
            fullBasketview.isHidden = true

        }

    }

    @IBAction func unwindBasketVC(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}

}


extension BasketVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !productsList.isEmpty {
            return sectionedProducts[section].count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasketCell", for: indexPath) as! BasketCell

        //        let basket = BasketModel.shared.records
        cell.basketImg.image = sectionedProducts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].img
        cell.basketName.text = sectionedProducts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
        cell.basketPrice.text = "\(String(describing: sectionedProducts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].price)) Руб."

        return cell
    }
```

Теперь мне нужно что если в данной секции в которой нету продукта она не отображалась а скрывалась ! На данный момент это выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите на картинке что присутствует только Топпинги в которых есть хлеб ! Как мне скрыть другие секции так как в них нету продуктов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может у кого то будет такая же проблема с простым методом то я решил этот вопрос и вот как он выглядит, элементарно

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if sectionedProducts[section].isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
    return sections[section]
}
```